# XSLT 2.0 Group Node-set checking descendant attributes

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the following node-set fragment:

```
<category value="Library">
    <category value="PACS">
        <category value="IMPAX (PACS)">
               <category value="Reporting"/>
        </category>
    </category>
</category>
<category value="Library">
    <category value="Enterprise Imaging">
        <category value="Desktops"/>
    </category>
</category>
<category value="Library">
    <category value="PACS">
        <category value="IMPAX (PACS)"/>
    </category>
</category>
```

Which is generated by the following:

```
<xsl:template name="categories">
<xsl:param name="topicmeta"/>
<xsl:variable name="VarCategories">

        <xsl:for-each select="map/topicmeta/category">
            <xsl:if test="contains(./data/@value, 'Library')">
                <xsl:if
                    test="string-length(./data/@value) - string-length(translate(./data/@value, '/', '')) &gt; 1">

                    <xsl:call-template name="category">
                        <xsl:with-param name="category" select="./data/@value"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="outputCategories">
        <xsl:with-param name="categories" select="$VarCategories"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to output:

```
<category value="Library">
    <category value="PACS">
        <category value="IMPAX (PACS)">
               <category value="Reporting"/>
        </category>
    </category>
    <category value="Enterprise Imaging">
        <category value="Desktops"/>
    </category>
</category>
```

I am trying to use the for-each-group

```
<xsl:template name="outputCategories">
    <xsl:param name="categories"/>
    <xsl:element name="categories">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="$categories/*" group-adjacent="@value">
         <xsl:sort select="@value"></xsl:sort>
         <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Which gives me:

```
<category value="Library">
  <category value="PACS">
     <category value="IMPAX (PACS)">
        <category value="Reporting"/>
     </category>
  </category>
```

I need to check each level and group each distinct value.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code into a recursive function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="mf xs">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(category)*">
        <xsl:param name="categories" as="element(category)*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$categories" group-by="@value">
            <category value="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()/category)"/>
            </category>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:param name="cats">
        <category value="Library">
    <category value="PACS">
        <category value="IMPAX (PACS)">
               <category value="Reporting"/>
        </category>
    </category>
</category>
<category value="Library">
    <category value="Enterprise Imaging">
        <category value="Desktops"/>
    </category>
</category>
<category value="Library">
    <category value="PACS">
        <category value="IMPAX (PACS)"/>
    </category>
</category>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($cats/category)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38ZB.

If you need the sorting as well then change the function to e.g.

```
<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(category)*">
    <xsl:param name="categories" as="element(category)*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$categories" group-by="@value">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <category value="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()/category)"/>
        </category>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>
```

As for the sample you have linked to in your comment, it puts its created `category` elements in the FO namespace, you either have to avoid that by doing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs exsl mf">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="status"/>    
    <xsl:param name="draft"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <index>


            <xsl:call-template name="categories"> </xsl:call-template>

        </index>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="categories">
        <xsl:param name="topicmeta"/>
        <xsl:variable name="VarCategories">

                <xsl:for-each select="map/topicmeta/category">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(./data/@value, 'Library')">
                        <xsl:if
                            test="string-length(./data/@value) - string-length(translate(./data/@value, '/', '')) &gt; 1">

                            <xsl:call-template name="category">
                                <xsl:with-param name="category" select="./data/@value"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>

                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($VarCategories/category)"/>


    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="category" xmlns="">
        <xsl:param name="category"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($category) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:element name="category">
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring-before($category, '/') = ''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$category"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($category, '/')"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:call-template name="category">
                    <xsl:with-param name="category" select="substring-after($category, '/')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(category)*" xmlns="">
    <xsl:param name="categories" as="element(category)*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$categories" group-by="@value">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <category value="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()/category)"/>
        </category>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or you have to make sure the paths in the function select the elements in that namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs exsl mf">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="status"/>    
    <xsl:param name="draft"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <index>


            <xsl:call-template name="categories"> </xsl:call-template>

        </index>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="categories">
        <xsl:param name="topicmeta"/>
        <xsl:variable name="VarCategories">

                <xsl:for-each select="map/topicmeta/category">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(./data/@value, 'Library')">
                        <xsl:if
                            test="string-length(./data/@value) - string-length(translate(./data/@value, '/', '')) &gt; 1">

                            <xsl:call-template name="category">
                                <xsl:with-param name="category" select="./data/@value"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>

                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group($VarCategories/*)"/>


    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="category">
        <xsl:param name="category"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($category) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:element name="category">
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring-before($category, '/') = ''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$category"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($category, '/')"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:call-template name="category">
                    <xsl:with-param name="category" select="substring-after($category, '/')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(category)*" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:param name="categories" as="element(category)*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$categories" group-by="@value">
        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <category value="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()/category)"/>
        </category>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works with the param but does not work when I try to process the node-set.I use a previous template that parses the information out of a file

Comment: The problem is caused by the use of a default namespace in your stylesheet which puts the created category elements in that namespace while my function as posted earlier selects elements in no namespace. I have edited the answer to show two alternatives, you can either make sure the created elements are in no namespace or you need to make sure the function makes sure it selects the elements in the namespace.